# MVC Routing issue for Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Area called Racing.  I have set up routes to accept parameters using constraints as below:

**Global asax:**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

**Route.config**

```
 public class RouteConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();


    }
}
```

**Racing area Registration**

```
public class RacingAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Racing";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
           // this maps to Racing/Meeting/Racecards/2014-01-06 and WORKS!!
            context.MapRoute(
               name: "Racecard",
               url: "Racing/{controller}/{action}/{date}",
               defaults: new { controller="Meeting", action = "Racecards", date = UrlParameter.Optional },
               constraints: new { date = @"^\d{4}$|^\d{4}-((0?\d)|(1[012]))-(((0?|[12])\d)|3[01])$" }
           );

            // this maps to Racing/Meeting/View/109 and WORKS!!
            context.MapRoute(
               "Racing_default",
               "Racing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller="Meeting", action = "Hello", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );





        }
    }
```

The above two work for the URL's specified but now I cannot visit for example Racing/Meeting/HelloWorld without having to pass a parameter as Racing/Meeting/HelloWorld/1.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your application_start from global.asax, the order in which you register your routes and area routes matters.

Comment: have you tried flipping the route definitions.  i.e make your ID route, the first one defined?

Comment: Yes I have tried flipping.  See edit for full code.

Comment: does any other method other than Meeting\Racecards take a date parameter?  more specifically do you need that route as generic as it is? could you explicitly define Meeting and Racecards in the url?  this would certainly prevent route confusion, but maybe too limiting for your use case.

Comment: If I change the URL to be url: "Racing/Meeting/Racecards/{date} then this still doesn't allow me to visit a normal controller/action without a parameter passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your area registrations need to be done before your Default route.
try moving them to the top of the method

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();


        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```